# Randomly extract .wav files (from folder) and related transcripts (from single text file)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I have a folder named wavs. Inside the same I've .wav files names in the format xxxxxxx_a999999 where xxxxxxx, a & 9999 are variables. Outside the wavs folder is a text file, naming the .wav file no & the transcripts of the same in the following format:

```
(xxxxxxx_a999999 transcript)
(xxxxxxx_a111111 transcript)
...
...
```

I need to select some wav files (randomly) and select the necessary transcript for the same. I can use either bash (that's the flavor of the toolkit I'm using) or Python. Could anyone suggest how should I do the same?

As requested, following is a concrete example:

```
( Arctic_a0001 "Author of the, danger trail, Philip Steels, etc." )
( Arctic_a0002 "Not at this particular case, Tom, apologized, Whittemore." )
( Arctic_a0003 "For the, twentieth time, that evening the two men shook hands." )
( c0589 " But the king refused, saying that the kingdom must go to the oldest son.")
( c0591 " Not until they were both dead, could the kingdom go to the third son.")
```

Assume, randomly I've selected 3 wav files, Now I want the related texts from this text file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus, I understand the same. It's just that I wanted a headstart in Bash as I'm struggling with this and I've a deadline. But I also understand it's flirting with community guidelines. I'm really sorry.

Comment: How is the transcript stored inside the single text file? Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @blhsing I've updated the question with a concrete example. Looking forward to some help.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.choice` to pick a wav file from the `wavs` directory, then use a generator expression to construct a dict, and then use the file name as an index to find the transcript:

```
from random import choice
import os
filename = choice(f for f in os.listdir('wavs') if f.endswith('.wav'))
transcript = dict(l.strip('() \n').split(maxsplit=1) for l in open('transcript.txt')).get(os.path.splitext(filename)[0], '').strip('" ')
```